# How do I restrict accepting only one type in my generic method?

Tags: java, types, generics

I have a generic function foo, which accepts any type and prints them out.

```
public static <T> T foo(T... arg) {
    List<T> foo = Arrays.asList(arg);
    for (T t : foo) {
      System.out.println(t);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

How do I make sure that the arguments received are of only 1 type. For example, {1,'a',3} should be invalid. It should either be all numbers or all characters. I want to accept either ALL integers or ALL Characters.

Comment: Did you check your method? Does it work for {1, 'a', 3} ?

Comment: @hgulyan: It will, because T will be inferred as type Object.

Comment: See my answer - this is possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can in fact do something like this:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> void f(T... args) {
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // all one type -- all of these compile!
    f(1, 2, 3); // prints "[1, 2, 3]"
    f('a', 'b', 'c'); // prints "[a, b, c]"
    f("a", "b", "c"); // prints "[a, b, c]"
    f(1D, 2D, 3D); // prints "[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]"

    // this is not preventable
    f(1, (int)'a', 3); // prints "[1, 97, 3]"

    // mixture of types -- none of these compile!
    //f(1, 'a', 3); // compilation error!
    //f(1, '2', "3"); // compilation error!
    //f("a", "b", 'c'); // compilation error!
    //f(1, 2, 3D); // compilation error!
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that:

- [`Integer implements Comparable<Integer>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)
- [`Character implements Comparable<Character>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)
- [`String implements Comparable<String>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
- [`Double implements Comparable<Double>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)

So to match those types (and possibly others), we bound `T` as follows:

- [`T extends Comparable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

This does include things e.g. [`java.util.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), which `implements Comparable<Date>`, and countless many other types, but is probably the best that you can do if you also want to allow `Integer` and `Character`.

---

Nonetheless, do keep in mind that `Integer`, `Character`, `String`, are all `Object`, so in fact a bunch of those mixed together **IS** a list of one type: `Object`.

Thankfully, it's **NOT** the case that `Object implements Comparable<Object>`; otherwise the above solution wouldn't work.

Comment: Clever.  BTW, do you live here?

Answer (score 1):

The `T` part means that all the `args` will be the same type.

If you wanted to restrict your generic type to be only a certain type or sub-type (e.g. Integer) you can do the following:-

```
public static <T extends Integer> T foo(T... arg) {
    List<T> foo = Arrays.asList(arg);
    for (T t : foo) {
      System.out.println(t);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: You can't just write that way. That will mean, he needs two different methods - one for numbers and one for characters.

Comment: Can you, please, bring an example in your question? How do you figure out which type to you need to accept?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a java developer but what you can do as one possible option is use generic collection of objects of type T.

```
public static <T> T foo(List<T> arg) { 
    List<T> foo = arg; 
    for (T t : foo) { 
      System.out.println(t); 
    } 
    return null; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want to do like this:

```
YourClass.<Type>foo(params);
```

Specifically:

```
YourClass.<Integer>foo(1, 2, 3);
```

and

```
YourClass.<Character>foo('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that `foo` returns the same type `<T>` as the input parameters.

You can infer `<T>` by defining the return type:

```
Integer i1 = 4;
String s = "string";

final Integer i2 = foo(i1, s); // error, only Integer allowed
```

If you do not specify a return type, the type `<T>` will be inferred as `Object`, and thus all sub-classes will be accepted.

Alternatively, as @Finbarr mentions, you can infer the type via

```
Foo.<Integer>foo(i1, s); // error, only Integer allowed
```

Answer (score -1):

To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name, followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound.

Following method will only accept numbers as it's parameters.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T firstNumber, T secondNumber)
{                      
   system.out.println(secondNumber.compareTo(firstNumber));
}
```

If you don't extend it with Comparable then `compareTo()` will not be available.